# How do you beat Redmourne the Trivern's immunity shields?

Tags: tiny-tinas-wonderlands

In the fourth difficulty tier of the Shattering Spectreglass mission, there is a three-headed wyvern.  However, it seems immune to all damage:  fire results in Immune text, electric results in Immune text, toxic results in Immune text, frost results in Immune text.

In most other Wonderlands bosses with immune sequences, there's something on the stage that allows you to resume damaging the boss.  And while there's a unique mountable cannon on one of the towers, it doesn't actually damage Redmourne.  There's a sewers under the boss arena, but I didn't see anything down there.

What do you need to do to damage Redmourne?

Comment: I'm fearful to understand your question properly, can you please Name the Game and attach a screenshot of the boss? coz I don't remember the "Shattering Spectreglass Mission" in tiny tinas wonderlands nor am sure about facing "Redbourne" if you could brief a bit more?

Comment: @AnubhavShriwastava Shattering Spectreglass is a post-release content part of the season pass

Answer (score 1):

Redmourne has immunity phases, it's not totally immune.

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Wonderlands/comments/x0juz5/latest_redmourne_fight_difficulty_design/):

> After you hit it 2-3 times you need to kill those spawning wyverns with different orbs blowing up around you to be able to land another 2-3 hits on Redmourne. Rinse and repeat.

By the way, some elements can't be used. Depending on the heads it has, Redmourne is immune to those elements:

- Difficulty 1 is fire immune
- Difficulty 2 is fire and toxic immune
- Difficulty 3 is frost and dark immune

So this could be true also for the last 3-headed version.